# Is there any option to view the recent files as in nautilus not just the recent file in a specific directory

Tags: vifm

Is there is an option to view the recent files similar to the "Recent" tab in nautilus? I know there is an option to view the recent file in a specific directory. But I want to see all the recent files on my PC.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no history of opened files.

You're not the only one to ask about it (already in `TODO`), so it might be added in the future. However, there are difficulties, because you can open files with `:!` and those cases are unlikely to be tracked reliably (might not even be desirable).